# Oracle SQL Developer does not open coming up in Windows restart and stop

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have downloaded correct Oracle database 11g Express edition.
then copied it to disk C, extracted it, then installed it. I downloaded `sqldeveloper-22.2.0.173.2018-x64` file as per laptop configuration.
then copied it to disk C, then extracted it. Then I installed it. And Created connection in it successfully. But after closing it

After some time I tried opening it again Now its not opening. When I checked in services. Some services are not running there.

[image]

And while reopening it, it is showing like this in image

[image]

Please help me in opening my Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Right click, then run Windows services for Oracle database. Open Oracle SQL Developer, try to connect. Tell me result.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing multiple problems here, but I'm going to address the one described in the title of your question and shown in your screenshot.

SQL Developer isn't opening...or well, it tries to, and just sits there.

In Windows explorer, find the AppData folder for your OS User. It may be hidden by default. From there, you want to go to Roaming Profiles, and then find the SQL Developer and system22.2... folder.

[image]

That last folder, the system22.2... - rename it to something else.

Then start SQL Developer again, it should come right up.

Comment: I used the mentioned steps and it worked like a charm. The only question asked was while it opened that would you like to import your settings from the previous version. I selected yes.
And window that was feeling shy for few hours came up. DING!